# Way for class template to deduce type when constructing an instance with std::make_unique?

Tags: c++, templates, decltype, template-argument-deduction

Let's say we have a class template `Foo`, that has one type template parameter that it can deduce from an argument in its constructor. If we use `std::make_unique` to construct an instance of `Foo`, is there a way for `Foo`'s constructor to deduce the template arguments as it would have if its constructor was called normally? Is this the simplest way to achieve this?

```
std::make_unique< decltype(Foo{...}) > (...);
```

This seems pretty clean but if `Foo`'s constructor takes a lot of arguments it can turn into a pretty ugly line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage a helper function to wrap the ugly code into a pretty wrapper.  That would look like

```
template <typename... Args>
auto make_foo_ptr(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_unique<decltype(Foo{std::forward<Args>(args)...})>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this enforce the template classes instantiated from `Foo` to be copy/move constructible because eventually it would have to be something like `auto x = make_foo_ptr();`?

Comment: @Zoso It does not, because the function is return a `unique_ptr<Foo>`, not a `Foo` and `unique_ptr<T>` is always moveable.  Also, from C++17 onward, even if it was returning a `Foo` and `Foo` is not moveable or copyable, it would still work thanks to C++17's guaranteed copy elision.